# Степень числа 10

Tags: c++, олимпиада, арифметика

> Программа должна прочитать из консоли натуральное число N. Если заданное число N равно 10 в M степени, то есть является некоторой степенью числа 10, то в ответ вывести число M. В противном случае вывести ответ No.

**Вхідні дані #1:
100**

**Вихідні дані #1:
2**

**Вхідні дані #2:
27**

**Вихідні дані #2:
No**

> Мой код проходит на 80%, не проходят два теста, помогите с кодом пожалуйста:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int N;
    int t = 1;
    cin >> N;
    if(N % 10 > 0 || N < 100)
    {
        start:
        cout << "No\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(N != 10)
        {
            if(N % 10 == 0)
            {
                N /= 10;
                t ++;
            }
            else
            {
                goto start;
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << t << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно входные ограничения?

Comment: Ограничений нет.

Comment: `if(N % 10 > 0 || N < 100)` - скажите это человеческим языком

Comment: Все просто, N % 10 > 0 – это если N будет делиться на 10 нацело, а N < 100 – это просто условие, что на то, что нет 10 в M степени при том что N < 100.

Comment: Вы, возможно, плохо понимаете прочитанное. Сформулируйте условие в `if` человеческими словами. А потом подумайте, что получится при `N` равном десяти.

Comment: Почему, вообще, число `сто` заслужило в Вашем коде отдельного упоминания?

Comment: @ValeraKvip Числа в нулевой степени в Вашем классе еще не проходили?

Comment: @Igor, ну да, посмотрел на код и начал искать проблему исходя из него.

Comment: @ValeraKvip - Нет, не вийдет так, потому что float не взаимно с оператором %

Comment: стоит заметить что число 1 тоже является степенью 10, 10^0 = 1, как, собственно и любое другое число в нулевой степени, возможно, что один из тестов, как раз с единицей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Читайте **строку**. Если это 1 и некоторое количество нолей — выводите это количество. Если нет — пишите No.

Интересно все же, какие ограничения на число `N`? Вот не верится, что это — *полное* условие. Дайте, кстати, URL задачи — посмотреть.

```
int is10power(const string& N)
{
    if (N[0] != '1') return -1;
    for(int i = 1; i < N.size(); ++i)
        if (N[i] != '0') return -1;
    return N.size()-1;
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/972boy

Comment: Повторяю на число N нет ограничений.

Comment: @DenysRusyn Тем более.

Comment: как сделать проверку, если будет 1 и некоторое количество нолей?

Comment: Посимвольно. Первый символ — 1? Нет? Пишем `No`. Да? Идем по всем остальным символам до конца строки и считаем... i-й символ в `string s` — `s[i]`. Нуль — `'0'`.

Comment: Вы мне предлагаете реализовать N через string?

Comment: А я о чем написал с самого начала?... Да, именно это я и предлагаю, особенно если учесть, что на N нет никаких — как вы утверждаете — ограничений...

Answer (score 1):

Я к сожалению не знаю как это сделать на `c++`, но попробую обьяснить так.
Если в числе есть не только единица и много нулей, следовательно, вывод `No`, иначе, вам надо посчитать сколько единиц в числе, если их больше чем одна, следовательно, вывод `No`, иначе, вам надо посчитать количество нулей в числе и вывести это, пример:

```
input = 1; output = 0
input = 10000; output = 4
input = 100; output = 2
```

вот и все решение )